# Extracting a link and save an attachment in it -- PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Am trying to extract a link from a email's body and save the attachment in that link.

```
$Folder = "InBox"
Add-Type -AssemblyName microsoft.office.interop.outlook
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$Email = $NameSpace.Folders.Item(1).Folders.Item($Folder).Items
$extracts = $Email | Where-Object {$_.subject -match "PITM*"}

$extracts | ForEach-Object {
    $email = $_.Body 
    #$lines = $email | Measure-Object -Line

    if($email -match '<(.*?)>'){
     "Match Found"     
     $url = $matches[1]          
     }
     $url
     $output = "H:\foo.DAT"

    $Process = new-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
    $Process.StartInfo.WindowStyle="Hidden"
    $Process.StartInfo.FileName="chrome.exe"
    $Process.StartInfo.Arguments=$url
    $Process.Start()    

}
        $Process.Dispose()
```

Email body looks like this:

> Number: PITM0008575
>   https://a.com/nav_to.do?uri=foo%3Fsys_id=58689b056f90a60002da186e6b3ee484%26sysparm_stack=u_production_item_list.do%3Fsysparm_query=active=true
>
> Requested due date:
>
> Fulfilled date:
>
> Completed date:
>
> Attachments:  Report foo.txt
>   https://a.com/sys_attachment.do?sys_id=829893456f90a60002da186e6b3ee402

Here are the two issues I've:

1. The script is not pulling up the second link.
2. I'm not able to save the attachment that is a result of opening the link.

Please help.

Comment: Hi, have you inspected `$matches`? If you want to download the file the links points to, I'm not sure Chrome is you best choice (maybe with IE automation, or `Invoke-WebRequest`).

Comment: Yes, matches[0] has the link within <> and matches[1] without. matches[2] is empty. I used IE but it threw an error that IE engine isn't available or is not configured (both are invalid as I've been using it for a while now). So used Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
#sample data
$email = "Number: PITM0008575
<https://a.com/nav_to.do?uri=foo%3Fsys_id=58689b056f90a60002da186e6b3ee484%26sysparm_stack=u_production_item_list.do%3Fsysparm_query=active=true>


Requested due date: 

Fulfilled date:

Completed date:

Attachments:  Report foo.txt
<https://a.com/sys_attachment.do?sys_id=829893456f90a60002da186e6b3ee402>"

$regex = [regex]"<(.*?)>"
$URLmatches = $regex.Matches($email)

$reportURL = $URLmatches.Groups[1].Value
$downloadURL = $URLmatches.Groups[2].Value

$output = "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\foo.dat"
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($downloadURL, $output)
```

Comment: Nice. The link could be extracted but with the Groups[3].Value. But the output has the html, not the attachment. I'll keep trying nonetheless.

Comment: Also, the URL redirects to a page that opens a download dialog. I tried two failed ways for this:  1. Use Webclient to download and save the file. 2. Open a IE object, navigate to the URL; create a WScript Shell and send the Save key. Any suggestions! (sorry not able to save the code)

Comment: I don't know what kind of web server you're connecting to, and if the URL is not predictable I'm afraid I can't help you any further here.